# Rails: Keep scopes encapsulated when using PostgreSQL, DISTINCT and ORDER together

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I’ve started migrating a Rails 4 application from SQLite to PG (PostgreSQL). I have a lot of scopes that I use for ordering (eg: scope :default_order, ->{order(:name)} ) that I merge to order my records in controllers.

With PG, when I do this:

```
User.joins(:shipments, :person).merge(Person.default_order).distinct
```

It complains that:

```
 ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

All my scopes are well encapsulated but now, it seems I need to manually write the select clause (with DISTINCT and dig into the model to pick the proper ordering column... like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1717152/178266). That doesn't sound right to me.

I've tried to 'add' to the select in the ordering scope (to keep it encapsulated, something like: .select(arel_table[:weight])) but it doesn't work.

The irony is that I've migrated all the manual selects ("DISTINCT ...") statements to ActiveRecord.uniq with Rails 3.2, but it looks like I need to do it all over again in the other direction!

Unless somebody has a good suggestion...

PS: The only workaround I see right now is the ugly:

```
User.joins(:shipments, :person).merge(Person.default_order).select('DISTINCT(users.*), people.name')
```

Comment: I don't think you can escape that PG restriction ([here's a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1717152/2622934)).  This is still ugly but provides a way to keep things encapsulated: `User.select("users.*").joins(:shipments, :person).merge(Person.select("people.name").default_order).distinct`.

Comment: cschroed, that doesn't help: because often enough, the order clause contains columns from another table.